# Are there similar gem for Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redactor

I tried a put in my blog formatting text, and I was find gem '*redactor*'.But whether it will work on rails 4 or is there something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand your question, but there's a [redactor-rails gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/redactor-rails) on [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org)

Comment: I know, I spoke about it.They write it to working for rails 3.2

Comment: most of the gems developed for rails 3 work with rails > 4, too. Give it a try!

Comment: redacator-rails gem works with rails 4. I am using it